# Can we load Schema (base schema) for OpenDJ using Novel Ldap api?

Tags: java-8, opendj, novell

We are using Novel Ldap Api for all LDAP operations, i want to load my base **schema ldif file** to opendj without restarting the openDJ server.

So far, post setup we are manually copying the schema file to /config/schema location and we wanted it to do through Java code.

Since we already using Novel Ldap for all LDAP operations (modify, delete, read, add entry), we have to use the same.
When i tried, iam getting below exception, is there any solution please share?

> SEVERE: Exception getting LDAP connection: LDAPLocalException:
>   com.novell.ldap.ldif_dsml.LDIFReader: Version line must be the first
>   meaningful line(on line 9 of the file) (82) Local Error
>           at com.novell.ldap.util.LDIFReader.(LDIFReader.java:156)
>           at com.novell.ldap.util.LDIFReader.(LDIFReader.java:80)

Comment: Without knowing your LDIF data I can only guess. But the error message seems to indicate that your LDIF files does not start with `version:` line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the Novell LDIF reader is strictly accepting LDIF version 1 from RFC 2849.
The first line should contain `version: 1`
OpenDJ does support adding schema over LDAP, it must be a change of `cn=schema`, adding values to the `attributeTypes` and `objectClasses` attributes.

Comment: Thanks for the details, you mean we can't add schema ldif file using Novell LDAP Api, but schema with changetype: modify should be fine. is n't it?

Comment: through changeType:modify, i added attributeTypes and objectClasses. Now it looks to be unable to load other ldif files due to an exception violates the Directory Server schema configuration because it does not include a structural objectclass. All entries must contain a structural objectclass

Comment: The schema and the entries must be compliant with the LDAP specifications. There are options in OpenDJ to relax some of those constraints, but that may result in unpredictive behaviors, and interoperability issues with specific client applications.

Comment: Thank you for the details, incorporated 'version' details to ldif file. Then able to load the ldif file using LDAPModifyRequest.